# The web page returns _Index of/page_ when I try to use .htaccess to remove the .html extension

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried multiple different codes, but it gave me the same results (not what i wanted):
Here's one code that I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to remove the .html extension on the url of the page: (example.com/page instead of example.com/page.html).

And on the html side I have

```
index.html
<a href = 'page'> go to page </a>
```

And the following is the content of page.html

```
page.html
<h1> Welcome to this page. </h1>
<p> Yesturday Stackoverflow paid everyone's dept... bla bla text. balbla. </p>
<a href = "more.html"> read more </a>
<a href = "contact.html"> contact us </a>
```

When I click on the "go to page" link on index.html, it goes to example.com/page. And the page only displays "Index of page" with a big font, and a list of links to more files on the "page" page (read more, contact). They are displayed in a table and it gives me the option to sort by the name, size, or last modified.
File structure:

```
> index.html
> page.html
> .htaccess
> _folder
     > abcd.html
```

So, what might be wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for detailed post. Could you please also let us know directory structure where is you htaccess resides and where are your html files reside? That will give better picture of your question thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSinfh13, they are all on the same directory. I edited the question btw — to give you a visual

Comment: This sounds like you had not only a file `page.html`, but also a folder named `page` in the same location?

Comment: Yes that’s what it is. I have a folder “page”, and a file “page.html”. Well at least I know what the problem is now. That answers my question, ‘what’s wrong’. But it also raises another question, how can I fix that, so that it goes to the file instead of the folder?